# Visual Studio iOS project on Windows > iOS Bundle Signing > Xamarin automatic provisioning gets "Automatic signing failed"

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

1. VS > File > New > Project > iPhone.. > iOS app
2. Proj properites > iOS Bundle Signing > Automatic Prov.. > Team selected...
   which got error:
   "Automatic signing failed.."

..Output window:

```
Resolving certificate...
Fetching valid and locally installed signing identities...
Syncing certificates for "The Software Factory, Inc." team...
Saving iOS Development certificates...
There was an error while trying to automatically provision the project, please check the logs.
```

Comment: Are you sure all the certificates are available on the mac machine?

Comment: try manual Provisioning , pick you signing identity, you provisioning profiles should appear if You setup the certificates correctly

Comment: G.hakim: I don't know.  I'm following Xamarin web Automatic Provisioning for Xamarin.iOS and it says to select Auto Prov and then select a team, is what fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic provisioning never worked.  Resorted to manual provisioning, and am now building and running on iPad device OK.

Comment: It seems to be very buggy indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening xcode project with the same bundle name of your project , add provision profiles . Then, restart visual studio.